# Can PWM speed regulation be connected behind the Zener diode?

Tags: pwm

[image]

The PWM signal will be connected to "Port".

Comment: It totally depends what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PWM signal can come from wide range of sources.

Your schematics looks good. This is an example of completing the circuitry.

> 1. Motor max: 1.5V / 500mA
> 2. Thus, Zener voltage = 1.5V
> 3. Max current of the Zener = Current through R1 with Motor disconnected 
>    = (3.7V - Vz) / R1 = (3.7V - 1.5V) / 10ohm = 0.22A => 0.5A
> 4. Size of R1: V_r1 x (Iz + I_motor) = (3.7V - 1.5V) x (0.22A + 500mA) 
>       = 1.58W => 2W resistor
> 5. FET should be
>    able to drive the Motor at 500mA => 1A FET.